# Form of analytic function given its real part is a function of |z|

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the general form of $f(z)$ given its real part only depends on $|z|$

Here is the beginning of my solution in which I get stuck:

We can write $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ on which the C-R equations hold.
We can be more precise and write: $u(x,y) = u(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$. We can therefore get a more precise expression of our C-R equations for this case:
$$\frac{\partial u(\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\partial x} = u'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}x = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
and similarily:
$$\frac{\partial u(\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\partial y} = u'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}y = \frac{- \partial v}{\partial x}$$

I then try to solve for $v$ by integrating with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively but do not see how this would have a solution. From the above, we can also directly get: 
$$-x\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = y \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

How should I go about working through this question? Maybe expressing the modulo with complex conjugates?

Any hints are most appreciated!

Comment: PDEs are not my thing, but I believe that $x \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$ is a reasonable PDE to solve. You could try attacking it with the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), for example.

Comment: @TheoBendit I have never taken a differential equations course, so this is a bit out of my range for now. Do you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: I did take a differential equations course, but it did barely anything with partial differential equations, and I remember basically none of it. I could try to work through the example, but honestly, my explanation would be no better than Wikipedia's. Further, if you're not already familiar with PDEs and their techniques, then I think there is probably another method for doing this problem that is more in line with what you're familiar with (but I personally don't see what it would be). Basically, I want to see if anyone else can answer the question better than I can, before I try.

Comment: Here's an idea:  observe that the equation $xv_x + yv_y$ says that $\vec r \cdot  \nabla v = 0$,  where $\vec r = (x, y)$ is the radial vector.  So you have shown that $v_r = 0$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that the real part of $f(z)$ depends solely on $\vert z \vert = r$; thus

$f(z) = u(z) + iv(z) = u(r) + iv(r,  \theta); \tag 1$

the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar coordinates are

$u_r = \dfrac{1}{r}v_\theta, \tag 2$

$v_r = -\dfrac{1}{r}u_\theta; \tag 3$

from (3) we find, since $u_\theta = 0$,

$v_r = 0, \tag 4$

and thus

$v_{\theta r} = v_{r \theta} = 0; \tag 5$

if we differentiate (2) with respect to $r$, and then substitute (2), (5) in the result, we obtain

$u_{rr} = -\dfrac{1}{r^2}v_\theta + \dfrac{1}{r}v_{\theta r} = -\dfrac{1}{r}u_r, \tag 6$

whence

$(\ln u_r))_r = \dfrac{u_{rr}}{u_r} = -\dfrac{1}{r}; \tag 7$

integrating with respect to $r$:

$\ln u_r = -\ln r + \ln C = \ln (Cr^{-1}), \; C \in \Bbb R; \tag 8$

$u_r = Cr^{-1}; \tag 9$

$u(r) = C\ln r + D, \; D \in \Bbb R; \tag{10}$

combining (2) and (9),

$v_\theta = ru_r = C; \tag{11}$

$v = C\theta + E, \; E \in \Bbb R; \tag{12}$

$f(z) = u + iv = C\ln r + D + iC\theta + iE = C(\ln r + i\theta) + (D + iE); \tag{13}$

with $z = re^{i \theta}$, $D + iE = \alpha \in \Bbb C$,

$f(z) = C \ln z + \alpha. \tag{14}$